# Stop creating log file if no logs are printed

Tags: java, log4j

I have the following simple Hello World:

```
public class App {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); 
//        log.info("Test info log");
    }
}
```

And have the following in `log4j.properties`:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,  file  
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Whenever I run the code, the empty `log.log` file is created even though the logging is commented out.

How to make it create a log file only if logs are printed?

Comment: Wouldn't it be useful to have a log-file even if it is empty? Just by that you know those routines are working in some way.

Answer (score 0):

This may give a solution for this if you know where the first log written to file. You can create the **file appender** when you need to log.

```
    public static void addFileAppender() {
        FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
        fileAppender.setName("FileLogger");
        fileAppender.setFile("feature.log");
        fileAppender.setLayout(new PatternLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"));
        fileAppender.setThreshold(Level.DEBUG);
        fileAppender.setAppend(true);
        fileAppender.activateOptions();
        Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(fileAppender);
    }
```

Comment: You mean to remove appender from `properties` file and add it like this before using any `log...` right?

Answer (score -1):

Log4j creates log file because you created logger `private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class);`. You are telling him that you want to write a log message, but because you commented usage of log he doesn't know what appender you will need and creates all of them.

### For example:

`log4j2.properties`

```
rootLogger.level=trace
rootLogger.appenderRef.file-info.ref = FileInfo
rootLogger.appenderRef.file-debug.ref=FileDebug

appender.file-info.type=File
appender.file-info.name=FileInfo
appender.file-info.fileName=info.log
appender.file-info.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file-info.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.file-info.filter.filter-info.type=LevelRangeFilter
appender.file-info.filter.filter-info.minLevel=info
appender.file-info.filter.filter-info.maxLevel=info

appender.file-debug.type=File
appender.file-debug.name=FileDebug
appender.file-debug.fileName=debug.log
appender.file-debug.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file-debug.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.file-debug.filter.filter-debug.type=LevelRangeFilter
appender.file-debug.filter.filter-debug.minLevel=debug
appender.file-debug.filter.filter-debug.maxLevel=debug
```

### case 1: will create only one file info.log with one message

```
public class App {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Test info log");
    }
}
```

### case 2: will create two empty files info.log, debug.log

```
public class App {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

### case 3: will create two files info.log (one message), debug.log (empty)

```
public class App {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Test info log");
        Doc doc = new Doc();
    }
}

public class Doc {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Doc.class);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this directly relates to the question I asked.

Comment: Question: `How to make it create a log file only if logs are printed?` In provided code example remove `private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(App.class);` because you are not using it to create log message and it confusing logger. Log4j is constructed to create log file only when you are logging some messages from the box. I showed you several examples how it works.